# jQuery attach button to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of links generated dynamically, where the elements look like this:

```
<li id="nod1"> 
    <span>
        <a onclick="javascript:getNodeProperties('1');">Element 1</a>
    </span>
</li>
<li id="nod2"> 
    <span>
        <a onclick="javascript:getNodeProperties('2');">Element 2</a>
    </span>
</li>
```

getNodeProperties() doesn't do anything currently.

I'm trying to make a jquery (or js function), so that when I click an element, a button will appear on it's right side and the button from the previously clicked element will disappear.

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/GpdgF/2104/) jsfiddle to better explain. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, if you want to display button in right side of `<a>` tag,and if you click on other `<a>` tag, the all other button should be hidden

```
window.getNodeProperties = function(nod_id){
    $("li").find(".buttonClass").remove();
    $("<input type='button'class='buttonClass'>").appendTo("#nod"+nod_id);
}
```

Comment: check with this code.i swear should work perfectly for your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Since you have told elements are dynamically added you have to use `.on()`, I would recommend to give a class name to those anchor tags.

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(){

    $("input.active").remove();
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "<input class='active' type='button' value='Click me'/>"); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**js**

```
   window.getNodeProperties = function(nod_id){
    $("#nod"+nod_id).find("span").remove();
    $("<input type='button'>").appendTo("#nod"+nod_id);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/2121/)

Comment: Thank you, but my main problem is: how do I make the previously spawned buttons disappear? There should only one button at any given time

Answer (score 0):

You should try and avoid setting the event handlers in your HTML. You can setup an event delegate for the `<a>` elements so that i will handle the event even if you add more  elements, without attaching new event handlers.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/2129/)**

```
$(".tree.well").on("click", "li span", function() {
    var but = $("<button>");
    but.text("New button");
    $(this).parent().append(but);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="tree well">
    <ul>
        <li id="nod1"> 
            <span>
                <a>Element 1</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li id="nod2"> 
            <span>
                <a>Element 2</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li id="nod3"> 
            <span>
                <a>Element 3</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```